# Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I get the following error whenever trying to run my spring boot Kafka application.

```
2020-08-04 20:17:23.366 ERROR 2827 --- [           main] o.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin  : Could not create admin

org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:479) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin.create(Admin.java:71) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient.create(AdminClient.java:49) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.initialize(KafkaAdmin.java:177) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaAdmin.java:157) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910) [spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) [spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) [spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at ai.kollie.kafka.KafkaApplication.main(KafkaApplication.java:19) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid url in bootstrap.servers: ${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:59) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:439) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Now, I have used `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` to set the server to `localhost:9092` and following are my producer, consumer and topic configuration files respectively.

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;
```

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;
```

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfig {

    @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
...
```

Am I doing something wrong or overlooking something?

**Update:**

The previous error is resolved. Although, now I'm facing the following issue.

```
2020-08-06 01:30:02.895  INFO 4090 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.5.0
2020-08-06 01:30:02.897  INFO 4090 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 66563e712b0b9f84
2020-08-06 01:30:02.897  INFO 4090 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1596657602893
2020-08-06 01:30:32.934 ERROR 4090 --- [           main] o.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin  : Could not configure topics

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Timed out waiting to get existing topics; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.lambda$checkPartitions$4(KafkaAdmin.java:254) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1341) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.checkPartitions(KafkaAdmin.java:233) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.addTopicsIfNeeded(KafkaAdmin.java:219) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.initialize(KafkaAdmin.java:189) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaAdmin.java:157) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910) [spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) [spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) [spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at ai.kollie.kafka.KafkaApplication.main(KafkaApplication.java:19) [main/:na]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:108) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:272) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.lambda$checkPartitions$4(KafkaAdmin.java:236) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

I have the created the topics that the application is using by creating `NewTopic` beans as follows:

```
@Bean
    public NewTopic userTestTopic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("test-user")
                .partitions(1)
                .replicas(3)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic employeeTestTopic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("test-employee")
                .partitions(1)
                .replicas(3)
                .build();
    }
```

Both the sides could communicate before despite of the previous error but cannot now. The terminal just lists out all the configs and stops, saying `Close timed out with 1 pending requests to coordinator, terminating client connections`. How do I resolve this?

Comment: what is the value of `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers`

Comment: Missing the closing `}`.

Comment: Thank you, @GaryRussell . Sorry I didn't notice that. I have bumped across a successive error. Kindly look into it.

Comment: Timeouts are often caused by incorrect SSL configuration (client doesn't match server configuration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid url in bootstrap.servers: ${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers

You are missing the closing `}`.

```
@Value(value = "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers")
private String bootstrapAddress;
```